# About warp voting function

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

The CUDA programming guide introduced the concept of warp vote function, "_*all", "*_any" and "__ballot".

My question is: what applications will use these 3 functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__ballot` is used in [CUDA-histogram](https://github.com/trantalaiho/Cuda-Histogram/blob/master/cuda_histogram.h) and in CUDA NPP library for quick generation of bitmasks, and combining it with `__popc` intrinsic to make a very efficient implementation of boolean reduction.

`__all` and `__any` was used in reduction before introduction of `__ballot`, though I can not think of any other use of them.

Answer (score 8):

The prototype of `__ballot` is the following

```
unsigned int __ballot(int predicate);
```

If `predicate` is nonzero, `__ballot` returns a value with the `N`th bit set, where `N` is the thread index.

Combined with `atomicOr` and `__popc`, it can be used to accumulate the number of threads in each warp having a true predicate.

Indeed, the prototype of `atomicOr` is

```
int atomicOr(int* address, int val);
```

and `atomicOr` reads the value pointed to by `address`, performs a bitwise `OR` operation with `val`, and writes the value back to `address` and returns its old value as a return parameter.

On the other side, `__popc` returns the number of bits set withing a `32`-bit parameter.

Accordingly, the instructions

```
volatile __shared__ u32 warp_shared_ballot[MAX_WARPS_PER_BLOCK];

const u32 warp_sum = threadIdx.x >> 5;

atomicOr(&warp_shared_ballot[warp_num],__ballot(data[tid]>threshold));

atomicAdd(&block_shared_accumulate,__popc(warp_shared_ballot[warp_num]));
```

can be used to count the number of threads for which the predicate is true.

For more details, see Shane Cook, CUDA Programming, Morgan Kaufmann

Comment: beautiful, the documentation on ballot and its successor is very sparse.  This gave me some intuition as to what `__ballot_sync` is doing.  Thanks @jackolantern!

Answer (score 1):

As an example of algorithm that uses __ballot API i would mention the In-Kernel Stream Compaction by D.M Hughes et Al. It is used in prefix sum part of the stream compaction to count (per warp) the number of elements that passed the predicate.

[Here the paper. In-k Stream Compaction](http://www.vmg.cs.bangor.ac.uk/Publications/InK-Compact.pdf)

Comment: This sounds super interesting. Is there any implementation I can look at?

Comment: yes, I wrote an improved version of that algorithm. https://github.com/knotman90/cuStreamComp . Please ask me if you need clarifications or benchmarks.

Comment: Actually it would be nice if you have some benchmarks against thrust library.  

Also I think that in line 78 of cuCompactor.cuh, it should be possible to have another global array called d_output_index which would contain the the value of idx corresponding to where the original data came from. Am I correct?

Comment: Also, I think you should add a LICENSE.txt file to your repo.

Comment: write me on github or visit davidespataro.it to get my email so we can discuss.

Comment: Cool. Found your email. I will write to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA provides several warp-wide broadcast and reduction operations that NVIDIA’s architectures efficiently support. For example, __ballot(predicate) instruction evaluates predicate for all active threads of the warp and returns an integer whose N*th* bit is set if and only if predicate evaluates to non-zero for the N*th* thread of the warp and the N*th* thread is active [Reference: Flexible Software Profiling of GPU Architectures].